# How to print the random.randrange number that was selected?

Tags: python

Can't seem to find an answer to this;
For example:

```
health -= random.randrange(0, 5)
```

How would I print out (edit: to the the console) what number was selected in the range to show how much health was deducted?

Comment: Whats wrong about storing it before use?

Comment: What's initial value for health?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends where you want to print it... In addition i hope that you initialized health variable to something and then use -= to decrease it... If you just want to print it to console you have to

```
print health #python 2.x
```

or

```
print(health) #python 3.x
```

of course you have to store the random number was selected

```
rand = Random.randrange(0,5)
print rand
```

Comment: yes don't worry its been initialized in a class, just wanted to know how to print out the randrange number to the console. edit: oh yeah of course I have to store it, sorry turns out this was a silly question. programming noob here...

Comment: No problem at all. We are here to help you out with your programming problems ;)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
rand = random.randrange(0, 5)
health -= rand
print rand
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are on python interpreter command, just type `health`. It will print it out. If you are doing through code, do 
`rand = random.randrange(0, 5)
print rand`